# How to map TFS to two local directories

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am working with a web application, using TFS.  Every time I build the site it takes an unproductivly long time to start up again.  I would like to have a second mapping of the site on my c drive, where I would only get latest and build once a day, so this version would always be fast.  This would be like a "readonly" directory as I wouldn't personally make any edits to it.

Please let me know if this possible, or if you have any alternative.

Comment: There are third-party build tools that you can call from TFS builds that can pre-compile your ASP files on IIS so that you don't have to wait forever and a day after hitting the site for the first time after every release.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue and belongs on SO but is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One workspace does not allow the same TFS folder to be mapped to more than one local directory.

However you can have two or more workspaces for one computer, and each workspace can map a TFS folder to a different local folder. What revisions of files are in each workspace is tracked separately (to keep each up to date you need to do a get in each: easy with ['tf get'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the command line).

Answer (score 3):

TFS has a build agent built in, you can create a build to run daily or nearly any other way you can think of, though you would have to set up something to be a build server i believe.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this.

1. Unmap Your TFS
2. Right click on the folder and Map the sub directory to a folder for example `C:\temp`
3. Click on the root and map it to another folder `C:\localDev\`
4. you will be asked to remove the existing mapping on `C:\temp`

   - Select No (do not press Cancel)

I have tried this and it works fine.