# Are there any concerns with one user mapping a TFS project to two directories?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I'm planning to map some of my TFS projects to two different directories as discussed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138960/how-to-map-tfs-to-two-local-directories).  I'll be using two different workspaces, both with the same Computer and the same Owner.

Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea?  Are there any complications with merging or locks that one user with two mappings would run into, that are different from the normal complications that two users checking out a project run into?

Basically, I want to keep all of my projects on a shared drive, all mapped to TFS, but then have additional second local mappings for the few projects I'm most actively working so that Visual Studio is faster.  I'm using VS 2010 with the TFS Power Tools Extension.

Comment: It seems like your saying that I should never work on two branches of a project at the same time (ex: bug fix + feature.) Is TFS really that bad?

Comment: I really don't know what is causing it and I don't hope it's representative for every installation. I just revoked the comment as I can't prove any of it. :) Branching and merging do work fine though, I stand corrected on that one. I would stay away from network folders though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'm mainly just trying to anticipate common issues I might run into. Can't really avoid managing some of my projects on the network, because my local workstation is too small.

Comment: I don't expect major issues with TFS here. Visual Studio and storing data on "untrusted locations" like a networkshare can cause major headaches. Also, multiple users mapping a workspace to the same network location can be very dangarous!